# What is the definition of a single bundle application in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I get this error when I try to validate my iPad app archive that I have build with XCode 4:

> “TVGuidePlusHD” does not contain a single–bundle application or
>   contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust
>   your scheme to create a single–bundle application.

I know about the "Skip install" setting, but still it fails for me.
The contents of the archive are these:
[image: Contents of archive]

So is the problem the tvguide.db file? This is my .sql document which is compiled automatically to a sqlite db file and actually is supposed to be copied to the application bundle only.

Comment: Shouldn't it be inside the bundle, then?

Comment: @Henning_Makholm Actually it is inside the bundle, also. I have not touched the setup for years, but after upgrading to XCode 4, I am not able to distribute by app. I am just trying to verify, if this could be the reason for the error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

After making sure that the tvguide.db file is not inside the "Applications" folder, then the archive is considered a single-bundle application and is validated correctly.